# Visual Force Email not pulling in address

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template

I'm trying to write a visual force email template, but I can't seem to pull in the address field for a new lead. I've read online that I should try to use MailingStreet since the address field is made up of a few separate fields, but this still is not working. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

```
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<p>You have received a new lead from {!relatedTo.LeadSource}</p>
<p>Lender: {!relatedTo.Selected_Lender__c}</p>
<h3>Lead details</h3>
<p>Name: {!relatedTo.name}</p>
<p>Credit Score: {!relatedTo.Credit_Score__c}</p>
<p>Daytime phone: {!relatedTo.Phone}</p>
<p>Best time to call: {!relatedTo.Best_Time_to_Call__c}</p>
<p>Email: {!relatedTo.Email}</p>
<p>City: {!relatedTo.city}</p>
<p>Province: {!relatedTo.state}</p>
<p>Additional Notes: {!relatedTo.application_notes__c}</p>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using:

```
<p>Address: {!relatedTo.street}</p>
```

seems to work!